# "add data driven subscription" missing in SSRS sharepoint mode

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013, ssrs-2012

I'm using sharepoint 2013 with SQL server 2012 Enterprise Edition SP2.
I am using SSRS in sharepoint integrated mode. When I hover over report options I see the "Manage Subscriptions" option and when I click it I can see the "add subscription" option. However, the "add data driven subscription" is missing for some reason. This option is available when I access the report server directly (as in the native mode).

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong. I need to have a SQL driven recipient list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Though the database server had Enterprise installation of SQL Server, the SQL Server components installed such as reporting services sharepoint add-in on the Sharepoint servers were of standard edition and not enterprise. Upgraded the edition by using the upgrade edition option in the sql server installation center on these servers. It started working fine then.

Answer (score 0):

I found the root cause: My report's design has a data-driven subscription on a report that contains the User!UserID expression.

I would have to remove it in order to run it for data driven subscription .